# Trailing zeros in scientific notation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having a hard time trying to add trailing zeros to the scientific notation in pgfplots! Has anyone ever done this?!

Combinations of `/pgf/number format/precision=2`, `/pgf/number format/sci` and `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill` doesn't work:(

My Code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth*0.5,
    height=\textwidth*0.5*0.65,
    xmin=-20, xmax=20, ymin=-800000, ymax=-600000,
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci},
    enlarge x limits=0.08,
    enlarge y limits={value=0.12,upper},
]
\addplot[only marks,yerr] table[x=Angle_Value, y=A_Value, y error=A_Error] {csv/w1_angle_test.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the image looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option you are looking for is the `sci zerofill` option; this is shown in the pgf manual under "number printing". You can change the number of trailing zeros with the `precision=1` option.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,
ymin=0.0,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1,sci,sci zerofill}]

 \addplot [black] coordinates  {
(0,1)
(5,10)
(25,100)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ..still so much to learn after 6 years of Latex:)